# How to configure JMS in Jboss 6?

Tags: java, jms, jboss6.x

I newbie to JMS(java Messaging service). I want to run sample JMS application using jboss 6.

I have tired searching google and got like [this](http://javafindings.wordpress.com/2013/05/16/java-messaging-service-jms-with-jboss-7-1-1-new/). Those link are refer jboss 7.

1.How to configure JMS in jboss 6?

2.Is there Jboss7 have in built-in  JMS? or need configure manually?

3.sample Application using Jboss 6?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally i got the link for sample jms application using Jboss 6.x.
There are two ways you can configure jms queue in jboss
1.Add message queue details in jboss/server/default/deploy/hornetq/hornetq.jms.xm

```
<queue name="myQueue">
  <entry name="/queue/MyQueue"/>
</queue>
```

2.create xml file in your workspace and add the message queue details

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="urn:hornetq"
    xsi:schemaLocation="urn:hornetq /schema/hornetq-jms.xsd" >

    <queue name="MyQueue2" >
        <entry name="/queue/MyQueue" />
    </queue>

</configuration>
```

Maintain this file under META-INF folder of in your workspace.

Refer this sample [application](http://theopentutorials.com/examples/java-ee/ejb3/how-to-create-ejb3-mdb-queue-project-in-eclipse-jboss-6-1/).

In this example includes
1.How to configure jms in jboss using hornetq.
2.Sending messages to jms message queue
3.Display messages from jboss server

Comment: What is different here from @Jakub K answer?

Answer (score 5):

In Jboss 7 (and 6 as well) you have bundled HornetQ server.
In Jboss 6 it is located in deploy\hornetq.sar. If you want to add destination you can specify it in hornetq-jms.xml file:

```
<topic name="myTopic">
  <entry name="/topic/myTopic"/>
</topic>
<queue name="myQueue">
  <entry name="/queue/myQueue"/>
</queue>
```

In Jboss 7 it looks like below:

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:messaging:1.1">
  <hornetq-server>
    <jms-destinations>
      <jms-queue name="myQueue">
        <entry name="queue/myqueue"/>
      </jms-queue>
      <jms-topic name="myTopic">
        <entry name="topic/mytopic"/>
      </jms-topic>
    </jms-destinations>
  </hornetq-server>
</subsystem>
```

You can find more information in HornetQ documentation

Comment: Thanks Jakub.I have configured xml file.After that what else i can do? Can you explain more?

Comment: Thanks.I dont know whether did you read questions fully or not. I am very newbie to jms queue.so I am expecting jms configuration and also sample application with how its works.

Answer (score 0):

Also you can put your own xml file name like `mysettings-hornetq-jms.xml`. Put it inside the `hornetq` folder in the `jboss6 > deploy` folder.

when name the xml use `-hornetq-jms.xml`  ( your name infront )

```
<configuration xmlns="urn:hornetq"
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xsi:schemaLocation="urn:hornetq /schema/hornetq-jms.xsd">

   <queue name="testQueue">
      <entry name="/queue/myQueue"/>
   </queue>

</configuration>
```