# Cannot find extension module org.jboss.as.messaging in Jboss standalone.xml

Tags: java, eclipse, jboss

I had open standalone.xml in my jboss configuration and found this extension:

```
<extensions>
    <extension module="org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan"/>
    <extension module="org.jboss.as.connector"/>
    <extension module="org.jboss.as.deployment-scanner"/>
    <extension module="org.jboss.as.ee"/>
    <extension module="org.jboss.as.ejb3"/>
    <extension module="org.jboss.as.jaxrs"/>
    <extension module="org.jboss.as.jdr"/>
    <extension module="org.jboss.as.jmx"/>
    <extension module="org.jboss.as.jpa"/>
    <extension module="org.jboss.as.jsf"/>
    <extension module="org.jboss.as.logging"/>
    <extension module="org.jboss.as.mail"/>
    <extension module="org.jboss.as.naming"/>
    <extension module="org.jboss.as.pojo"/>
    <extension module="org.jboss.as.remoting"/>
    <extension module="org.jboss.as.sar"/>
    <extension module="org.jboss.as.security"/>
    <extension module="org.jboss.as.threads"/>
    <extension module="org.jboss.as.transactions"/>
    <extension module="org.jboss.as.web"/>
    <extension module="org.jboss.as.webservices"/>
    <extension module="org.jboss.as.weld"/>
</extensions>
```

Now I cannot find the messaging extension module which i want to configure my JMS.

Comment: what jboss version did you use? are you using jboss7?

Comment: Please have a look this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20851629/how-to-configure-jms-in-jboss-6

Comment: You cannot find that in your standalone.bat. What you mean is standalone.xml in where you can find that extensions.

Comment: ahh yes, sorry about that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your are using jboss 6, in order for to you to find the messaging extension module. You should have opened standalone-full.xml which i believe you can find this extensions:

```
<extensions>
<extension module="org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan"/>
<extension module="org.jboss.as.cmp"/>
<extension module="org.jboss.as.connector"/>
<extension module="org.jboss.as.deployment-scanner"/>
<extension module="org.jboss.as.ee"/>
<extension module="org.jboss.as.ejb3"/>
<extension module="org.jboss.as.jacorb"/>
<extension module="org.jboss.as.jaxr"/>
<extension module="org.jboss.as.jaxrs"/>
<extension module="org.jboss.as.jdr"/>
<extension module="org.jboss.as.jmx"/>
<extension module="org.jboss.as.jpa"/>
<extension module="org.jboss.as.jsf"/>
<extension module="org.jboss.as.jsr77"/>
<extension module="org.jboss.as.logging"/>
<extension module="org.jboss.as.mail"/>
<extension module="org.jboss.as.messaging"/>
<extension module="org.jboss.as.naming"/>
<extension module="org.jboss.as.pojo"/>
<extension module="org.jboss.as.remoting"/>
<extension module="org.jboss.as.sar"/>
<extension module="org.jboss.as.security"/>
<extension module="org.jboss.as.threads"/>
<extension module="org.jboss.as.transactions"/>
<extension module="org.jboss.as.web"/>
<extension module="org.jboss.as.webservices"/>
<extension module="org.jboss.as.weld"/>
</extensions>
```

Check from the list of extensions above, there is the org.jboss.as.messaging.

Hope this helps.

**In addition to that:**

If you are using Command prompt and started the jboss-as by typing `standalone.bat`, well then you cannot access the messaging extension by running standalone.bat itself. For you to be able to access the messaging extension from the standalone-full.xml, you should run your jboss-as like this:

`JBOSS_HOME_SERVER_1\bin\standalone.bat -c standalone-full.xml`

by that you can now have the messaging in your jboss-as. For more info please refer to this link: https://wadsashika.wordpress.com/2014/09/20/configure-a-jms-queue-in-standalone-xml-of-jboss-as7/

Enjoy!

Comment: Thank you for this sir! Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Since your are using jboss 6, in order for to you to find the messaging extension module. You should have opened standalone-full.xml which i believe you can find this extensions:

```
<extensions>
    <extension module="org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan"/>
    <extension module="org.jboss.as.cmp"/>
    <extension module="org.jboss.as.connector"/>
    <extension module="org.jboss.as.deployment-scanner"/>
    <extension module="org.jboss.as.ee"/>
    <extension module="org.jboss.as.ejb3"/>
    <extension module="org.jboss.as.jacorb"/>
    <extension module="org.jboss.as.jaxr"/>
    <extension module="org.jboss.as.jaxrs"/>
    <extension module="org.jboss.as.jdr"/>
    <extension module="org.jboss.as.jmx"/>
    <extension module="org.jboss.as.jpa"/>
    <extension module="org.jboss.as.jsf"/>
    <extension module="org.jboss.as.jsr77"/>
    <extension module="org.jboss.as.logging"/>
    <extension module="org.jboss.as.mail"/>
    <extension module="org.jboss.as.messaging"/>
    <extension module="org.jboss.as.naming"/>
    <extension module="org.jboss.as.pojo"/>
    <extension module="org.jboss.as.remoting"/>
    <extension module="org.jboss.as.sar"/>
    <extension module="org.jboss.as.security"/>
    <extension module="org.jboss.as.threads"/>
    <extension module="org.jboss.as.transactions"/>
    <extension module="org.jboss.as.web"/>
    <extension module="org.jboss.as.webservices"/>
    <extension module="org.jboss.as.weld"/>
</extensions>
```

Check from the list of extensions above, there is the `org.jboss.as.messaging`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you so much sir. I finally found the extension module. But i cannot find it in my jboss console after i open localhost:9990. I cannot find the messaging there. Please help.